# Visual Studio C# Ignore an Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way in C# that I can signal to VS to force it to ignore an error on a specific line?

I have a variable, pos2, that is only initialized some of the time (it's random). However, when it is initialized, I set a flag at the same time.

```
pos2 = new Vector3(2.5F, 0.624F, 75F);
secondCar = true;
```

Later on in the code (behind my flag check), I use pos2 normally, and the editor throws an error. I use this script regularly, so I know it's not broken, and since pos2 is behind the flag check, I know I will never reach a point where pos2 is used when undeclared.

In Python, you can use "@UnusedVariable" or something like that (I don't remember exactly), but my VS editor keeps on throwing me an error for this, and I know that it will never reach this situation.

Comment: The compiler doesn't perform a deep enough analysis to reliably detect that you only ever use the initialized value of pos2.  That requires solving the halting problem.  Consider using Nullable get rid of the *secondCar* variable.  Solves this error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `Vector3?` ([nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)) instead of `Vector3` as there is no way to suppress the error.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for. I just didn't know it! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are getting as CS165 error about the use of an unassigned local variable. Simply put there is no way to suppress this message.  Warnings in C# are suppressible but errors are not.

Today the code may indeed be correct and the uses properly predicated on appropriate gates like the `secondCar` you mentioned.  However these logic gates may not be obvious to the next developer or even yourself a week or so from now.  Attempting to suppress a valid error like this in C# is just opening the gate for future problems down the road.

Instead of trying to fight the compiler here I would recommend working with it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want to initialize the variable to `null` or some other default value.  That way the error will go away, rather than just being suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942238/list-of-pragma-warning-disable-codes-and-what-they-mean) for more details, but generally, you can use `#pragma warning disable` to disable warnings.

... I assume you do mean warnings, right? If it is an error, your code won't compile, so you can't ignore that. But you can ignore warnings. If you are really getting an error, just use a variable initializer, like this:

```
int someVariable = 0;
YourClass someInstance = null;
```

Then the compiler won't complain about uninitialized variables.

Comment: I believe the OP is hitting CS 165 which is an error. Not 100% sure on this but the question seems to point to that

Comment: And I totally agree with you, JaredPar, that using uninitialized variables like this is going down the road to unmaintainable code. I would never do this with a production app. (But I confess I have done it with apps that are for me and me alone -- things like bootstrapping a database, that will be thrown away when done.)