# Non-returning code marking attribute? (__attribute__ ((noreturn)))

Tags: c#, attributes

What is equivalent of GCC `__attribute__ ((noreturn))` attribution in C#? To suppress warning about no `return` statement in a method on bad execution flow. My code will throw an error by calling error thrower function. I am using Mono included in Unity3D 4.0.

Comment: this might help (?) Maybe harder with mono... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942238/list-of-pragma-warning-disable-codes-and-what-they-mean

Comment: Can you not just `throw` ? Or just out a throw underneath the method that already throws?

Comment: @MarcGravell First, just throwing is not an option, because I want to reduce complexity by abstracting everything into one function call like C style. Second, I don't understand what you mean latter statement. Can you explain me a little more?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus And writing `#pragma` for each occurrence is not an option too because it increases code to write which is just opposite of what I want to do.

Comment: @Eonil if you know `SomeMethod` throws, but the compiler doesn't know that - then you could just `throw new Whatever()` after that call - it won't get hit  anyway

Comment: @MarcGravell Unfortunately, it doesn't reduce code amount or complexity too. I know C# has nice attribute like `Conditional` which changes compiler behavior, so I am betting on method-level attribution which will make compiler to treat a function call like a `throw`.

Comment: Write a method that returns an exception.  You can have it perform side-effects as required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999181/is-there-a-standard-never-returns-attribute-for-c-sharp-functions

Answer (score 0):

The C# is smart.  If you a have a method that returns a values, but you `throw` an exception then it will not generate a warning.

```
int foo(int bar)
{
    if (bar > 0) return bar + 1;
    throw new NotSupportedException(); 
}
```

No warnings are generated.

However, if it did generate a warning you can use `#pragma warning`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(v=vs.80).aspx